# CSS Modules - `compose` defined on `media-query` overrides styling outside of `media-query`

Tags: css, css-modules

I have a project where `css modules` works without an issue and recently I started incorporating responsiveness on it.
Our current setup is that we have a `typography.css` where we define several properties for each *type* of letter size and we do `compose` to import that setup where we require it.
My current use-case is the following.

```css
/* somefile.module.css */
.header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;

  composes: s-text from '../../styles/shared/typography.css';
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .header {
    composes: xs-text from '../../styles/shared/typography.css';
  }
}
```

```css
/* typography.css */
.s-text {
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: -0.01px;
  line-height: 16px;
}

.xs-text {
  font-size: 11px;
  letter-spacing: -0.006px;
  line-height: 14px;
}
```

Once I started using the `media-query`, on screen sizes larger than `600px` I'm still seeing the `composes: xs-text from '../../styles/shared/typography.css';`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and tried different hacks to make it work, but I suggest using `SASS` with the modules so you could use a basic `@mixin` to make it work.

Apparently, the `composes` property works the same as `@extend` in `SCSS` which means it is impossible to use it across media queries.